# How can I define an interface for a object/array containing key/value pairs as well as nested objects?

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm typing up a localization-library, and I'm aiming to have it strongly typed (as it will be re-used in multiple angular-applications) and - at the same time - backwards compatible so that we won't have to re-write all existing localization-files.

However, the structure of said localization-files is causing me a bit of a headache. Per example:

```
{
  'any-random-key': 'This is a string',
  'another-random-key': {
    'random-key': 'This is a string'
  },
  'yet-another-random-key': {
    'random-key-2': 'This is a string',
    'random-key-3': {
      'random-key-4': 'This is a string',
      'random-key-5': {
        'random-key-6': 'This is a string'
      }
    }
  },
  'and-yet-another-random-key': {
    'random-key-6': {
      'random-key-7': {
        'random-key-8': 'This is a string'
      },
      'random-key-9': 'This is a string'
    }
  }
}
```

Now - I suppose I could say that the service accepts `translations: any` or `translations: object` - but that's a little too random (no pun intended) for my liking.

So I tried using two different interfaces:

```
export interface ITranslation {
  [s: string]: string;
}

export interface ITranslations {
  [s: string]: ITranslation;
}
```

However that fails on `any-random-key` saying: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ITranslation'`

So I tweak my `ITranslations`-interface so that it becomes

```
export interface ITranslations {
  [s: string]: ITranslation | string;
}
```

Which fixes the above error, but introduces a new one on `'and-yet-another-random-key'` saying `Property ''and-yet-another-random-key'' is incompatible with index signature.`

At this point I am a little stumped. Is what I am trying to achieve (strong typing of the legacy structure) simply not plausible?

Comment: Is the level of nesting arbitrarily deep? For `'and-yet-another-random-key'` it is 3 levels deep, while your interface only handles 2-level deep objects.

Comment: This looks like tree structure

Answer (score 2):

For any arbitrary level of nesting (in other words, your data object can be as many levels deep as you want), you can simply self-reference the interface as such:

```
/** @interface */
export interface ITranslations {
  [s: string]: ITranslations | string;
}
```

[See the above example on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PQKhAIAEEsDsBcCmAnAZgQwMaPCYAoRADwAcB7ZecOJNLHASQBVl1YBnAG3XmjI-ABvfOHABtdgC5w7eMjgBzALrTmrDt17924AD4y5igNz4AvvnyZtVACY90qlmy48+AgLxCR4AORsAngC06jZkALaBANaI-j7SPkwAFtA6KeDoBvKwCj4ANN5+sGTwiSjBbKER0bHSwqKiPiHhUTFxvklpaRmyWTnepvkN-ojwgWzFpcjlsJUtNV71vk1VMYEATG0Jyak63YbZed4Ny3OBAMxtdYtLFc3VgQAsmx076ZmKh9c3M3erAKyXI7XRq3FZBABsz221F27wOQNE5kWSPAAwKFUCw1G4xKZRO1UBixBPzBgUhtQR31m9wA7ISvlTfkEABxQzqwnofSlor7E6mrACcbNee16PiBKPMpiMQA).

---

If you want to only allow 3-level deep nesting, then the interface will have to be verbose: TypeScript does not allow you to define how "deep" (i.e. the degree of nesting):

```
/** @interface */
export interface ITranslations<T = string> {
  [s: string]: T | string;
}

/** @type */
export type ITranslationsMax3Levels = ITranslations<ITranslations<ITranslations<ITranslations>>>;

const data: ITranslationsMax3Levels = { ... }
```

[See the above example on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PQKhAIAEEsDsBcCmAnAZgQwMaPCYAoRADwAcB7ZecOJNLHASQBVl1YBnAG3XmjI4A8TcAF5w7eMjgBzAHzgA3vnDgA2uwBc4yTIC6W4QB9tU2NIDc+AL758oCJHgBPEjjyFSFKs9fhmrDm5efnYAWXQiAGYAGUQAN0ROdlE-FjYuHj5Bf3SgrPYBHMDMkMK04uCOWWrLfEwQqgATHnQtIozKsIiY+MTksSUVAHI2JwBaAMayAFsxgGtEJyGtIaYAC2hkzfB0ExkhgBplcBHYMng1lAm2KdmFpa1BlRPJmfnF5ZP17e3diVNpENjlYjsMnIh4GM2OdLshrrBbu8HopjsNXndFmMAEyfVYbLbJP46MyHVEvG5ve5jSKfJ7PckIymYgAsuO+BJ2exJoPpDMRVIArLSyfShuikWMAGxs-HUQlcwEi8A2ekq5U806NMbgyHQi5XcX3YWiw2Y6WPJViikY8YAdmNvLR1olAA4ZT95f99kqQZbTeMAJzujlEgFA1XA6zmIA).

Answer (score 1):

Seems the solution was easier than I dared hope for:

```
export interface ITranslations {
  [s: string]: ITranslations | ITranslation | string;
}
```