# TS type of an object with different amount of props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make an instance for an object of different amount of pairs key: value, that I'm passing to a component.
So it might be:

```
id: 1,
food: 'apple',
}
```

another time :

```
sale: 385,
name: 'strawberry',
people: 43,
...
}
```

So, I don't sent the same object every time.

```
interface Props {
  [key:string]: string | number; // this is doesn't work
}

const Specs:FC<Props> = ({ items }) => {
  const newItems = Object.entries(items).map(([key, value]) => (
    <Item key={uid()} name={key} value={value} />
  ));

  return <ul className={`specs__list`}>{newItems}</ul>;
};

export default Specs;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's the definition of `items` prop

```js
interface Props {
  items: {
    [key:string]: string | number;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I've tried something similar but stucked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I've found here - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267444/how-can-i-define-an-interface-for-a-object-array-containing-key-value-pairs-as-w)

but want to know what other ways of defining such objects.

```
interface PropType<T = string> {
  [s: string]: T | string;
}

type Props = PropType<PropType>;

const Specs:FC<Props> = ({ items }) => {
  const newItems = Object.entries(items).map(([key, value]) => (
    <Item key={uid()} name={key} value={value} />
  ));

  return <ul className={`specs__list`}>{newItems}</ul>;
};

export default Specs;
```